# Additional drivers for my NVIDIA 680GTX not showing up in the additional drivers tool

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, jockey

Did a fresh 13.04 install "Additional drivers" doesnt show anything at all.
Was working fine on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have 2 nvidia cards installed 680GTX and 460GTX both detected on lspci, currently my system looks like its running on the Nouveau driver (Gallium 0.4 on NVE4)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 680] (rev a1)

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] (rev a1)

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

**EDIT:**

Or

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-313-updates` as suggested by @GM-Script-Writer-62850 in the comments.

This will install the latest NVidia drivers. After that you can select from the Additional Drivers list.

Comment: Probably should install the `nvidia-313-updates` packages as it will have a newer driver, if not that use the [xorg edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) for the `nvidia-319` beta driver