# NVidia (GTX 680) Drivers Ubuntu 13.04 Black Screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, graphics

I've been trying for two days now to get my computer running the NVidia drivers. I'm running a GTX 680 and 64 bit architecture.

I've tried multiple things, here's a few:

- [Additional drivers for my NVIDIA 680GTX not showing up in the additional drivers tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286442/additional-drivers-for-my-nvidia-680gtx-not-showing-up-in-the-additional-drivers)
- http://linuxg.net/install-new-nvidia-drivers-nvidia-319-17-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138983
- http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-Latest-Nvidia-Drivers-in-Ubuntu-13-04-350497.shtml

The Additional Drivers tab shows nothing, but I have used `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` and pretty much every other nvidia package I could find using `apt-cache search nvidia`

I've downloaded the .run file from NVidia's website, and logged out, started a VTY session, stopped lightdm, installed it, and rebooted, multiple times.

No matter the approach, the outcome seems to be the same. The system boots, I can hear the splash screen, where I am supposed to log in, but the screen is black, and backlight is off. I can't get into any VTY session like that, I have to reboot and add `nomodeset` to the boot options. I still get a black screen when I let it go to the login screen, but I can get in a VTY session. Regardless, I have yet to be able to fix it.

**Edit 1**

Not sure of the importance, but I am running a 2560x1600 native resolution monitor, if that somehow plays into it at all.

Comment: Isn't that an Nvidia Optimus system?

Comment: I have no clue. I've tried so many different installation methods. I chose GeForce->680 (not M)->Linux 64 and used that .run file.

Comment: Run `lspci` and look for the VGA controllers. Is there only the Nvidia?

Comment: This is the output from `lspci` http://pastebin.com/2G9hTXx5

Comment: Is this a desktop system with the Nvidia card in an expansion slot or a laptop? I don't think that the resolution would be the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a desktop. This is the exact card: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130768

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8801/discussion-between-grimpitch-and-robert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NVIDIA card is connected to a 27" monitor made by Catleap. It doesn't communicate it's capabilities well through EDID, and xserver can't work out what resolution and refresh rate to use. The following `xorg.conf` solves the problem:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 313.30  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05)  Wed Mar 27 16:37:22 PDT 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       88.8
    VertRefresh     59.5
    Option         "DPMS"
    Modeline       "2560x1440_60.00" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 +HSync -VSync
    DisplaySize    597 336
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    Option         "UseEDID" "False"
    Option         "UseEDIDDPI" "False"
    Option         "UseEDIDFreqs" "False"
    Option         "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "True"
    Option         "metamodes" "2560x1440_60 +0 +0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

there is only one way I succeeded for Ubuntu 13.04 and lucky you, it is very easy :)

1st Download driver on nvidia website : NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run (It was this in my case)

2nd Create /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf and write inside

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
blacklist nvidia-173
blacklist nvidia-96
blacklist nvidia-current
blacklist nvidia-173-updates
blacklist nvidia-96-updates
alias nvidia nvidia_current_updates
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

3rd Reboot

4th It will reboot in low resolution but it is fine for now.

1. Press CTRL+ALT+F2 and login
2. Go in the folder where you have downloaded NVidia Driver ie 'cd Downloads'
3. sudo chmod +x NameOfFileDriver.run
4. sudo service lightdm stop
5. ./NameOfFileDriver.run  --> It will run the install :)
6. Type reboot :D

Answer (score 0):

if you are already stuck on similar pb, i posted an answer that seems to fixed this for me there : [Installing NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 on Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320299/installing-nvidia-geforce-gtx-560-on-ubuntu-13-04/383750#383750)