# Clevo w650sr, nvidia 750m driver problem

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have just bought an Clevo w650sr, everything work except the nvidia graphic card.
It has nvidia 750m together with a haswell CPU, Core i7-4700MQ.

I have done some research and found out that I need the Nvidia 319 driver (or never). So I have tried installing that. I have tried installing it from both the Nvidia website, and from the xorg edgers ppa. But I can't get it to work. After I have installed the driver, Unity is gone, and the GUI around the programs. I have tried doing

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

But after this, I just get a 600x480 resolution.
If I search in "additional drivers" I find nothing. There is noe option in BIOS to "hard set" the GPU to the Nvidia one. I have also tried installing Bumblebee without any luck.

I have also search around on askubuntu, but I can't find anyone that have gotten an 750m to work with haswell CPUs.

- [Installing NVIDIA driver causes black screen (750M)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298375/installing-nvidia-driver-causes-black-screen-750m)
- [Installing NVIDIA driver causes black screen (750M)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314280/nvidia-gt-750m-graphics-problem-with-dual-boot-in-my-lenovo-ideapad-y500)

  I have tried with Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04 and 13.10 "beta"

Comment: Please let me know if you need some file output or anything, I'm not really sure what you guys are looking for. :)

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a "Tuxedo Book DC1502" with a Core i7-4702MQ and a Nvidia 750M GT running flawlessly under Ubuntu 12.04.2 (64 bit). The Nvidia 750M GT works properly as I already used it to play Dota 2.

I bought the laptop here (sorry, German only):
http://www.linux-onlineshop.de/Linux-Hardware/Linux-Notebooks/15-6-Zoll/Tuxedo-Book-DC1502-15-6-matt-Full-HD-IPS-NVIDIA-Geforce-GTX-750M-Grafik-drei-HDD-o.-SSD-bis-Intel-Core-i7-4900MQ-bis-24GB-RAM-DVD-o.-Blu-Ray-Brenner.geek
Both the specs and the Bios say, that it's just a rebranded Clevo W650SR, so the following recommendations should also work for your laptop.

To get the Nvidia 750M GT working I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04.2 (64 bit) in the standard Bios mode (not UEFI!), updated Ubuntu with apt-get and installed afterwards the proprietary Nvidia drivers and Bumblebee following this guide (sorry, again German only): http://www.linux-onlineshop.de/forum/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=3

The only thing you have to do is to open a terminal and type the following commands (for Ubuntu 12.04):

```
sudo su
add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
apt-get -y install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-generic-lts-quantal nvidia-319 && reboot
```

(currently I'm using the Nvidia driver 325.15, but this is how I started from the beginning)

If you are using Ubuntu 13.04 you should instead type the following commands:

```
sudo su
add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
apt-get -y install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic nvidia-319 && reboot
```

After that you can use Bumblebee to run a certain application with your Nvidia card. Just type:

```
optirun program
```

in your terminal, where "program" stands for any application you want to run on the 750M GT.

To test the performance increase of the Nvidia card in respect to the integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600 just type:

```
glxspheres
```

in the terminal. It's a small graphics benchmark to test the performance.
Now stop the benchmark and type:

```
optirun glxspheres
```

The benchmark will run now on your Nvidia graphics card and should show a better performance.

If you want to see the Nvidia settings, just type:

```
optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
```

in the terminal.

Hope it helps,
Quando

Answer (score 0):

As it happens I did the same installation procedure on a Samsung Series 5 550P7C S04 today. This laptop has an Ivybridge processor (with HD Graphics 4000) and a Nvidia 650M GT and was running under Ubuntu 12.04.2 (64 bit): Of course I wanted to use the Optimus technology. I forgot, that the new stable Nvidia driver was already 325.15 and just copied the above commands:

```
sudo su
add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
apt-get -y install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-generic-lts-quantal nvidia-319 && reboot
```

Well, no problem there: Although I typed "nvidia-319" still the newest Nvidia driver 325.15 was installed. So you don't have to modify these lines to get the newest Nvidia driver: If you want to, I assume you have to type "nvidia-325" instead of "nvidia-319", but, as I said, that doesn't seem to be necessary.

Regarding my Tuxedo Book (= Clevo W650SR): The Nvidia driver was updated automatically using apt-get (so, if you already have this setup, you don't have to do anything, the driver will be updated automatically - as it should ;)).