# Does Ubuntu 13.10 run well on Alienware 14 laptops?

Tags: alienware

Does Ubuntu 13.10 run well on Alienware 14 laptops? My specs are:

```
- Processor: 4th Generation Intel Core i7-4700MQ Processor (6M Cache, up to 3.4GHz)
- Memory: 8GB DDR3L at 1600 MHz(2 x 4G)
- Hard Drive: 750GB 7200RPM SATA 6Gb/s
- Video card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M with 16B GDDR5.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Only you can answer this question. Download the ISO file from http://www.ubuntu.com/ burn it into a DVD or create a bootable USB drive. Boot from it and choose "Try Ubuntu without Installing." When you are satisfied, please answer your own question and mark it as correct with green check mark.

Comment: Alienware provides laptops with Ubuntu pre-installed : http://www.alienware.com/ubuntu/

Comment: I really don't believe this question is opinion-based. cprofitt answer below is, IMHO, a proof that it is not. BTW, is this the correct place to comment about moderation?

Comment: I've successfully installed debian with 3.12 kernel on this laptop, works just fine, I think ubuntu will run too, just check that it has a new kernel (3.2 failed to boot).

Answer (score 3):

The only potential issue would be the Graphics card. That particular card uses Optimus which has been known to cause issues with Ubuntu and other Linux distributions. If the bios allows you to turn off Optimus and specify either Nvidia or Intel as the graphics card there should not be an issue.

There are some questions her about your video card:

- [Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348614/bumblebee-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-geforce-750m-and-driver-319)
- [Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298375/installing-nvidia-driver-causes-black-screen-750m)

The other items that can cause issues are:

- Web Camera
- Sound Card
- Backlit Keyboard
- Special Function Keys

Does your system have any of those items?

If you already own the system or have access to one you could try booting to an Ubuntu live CD to see how things work.

### Update

It would appear that there are some potential issues - I found this thread: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4457/t/19530230.aspx

Comment: `sudo lshw -C network` will show your network card information

Comment: That assumes he is running Ubuntu on the machine already -- it sounds like this could be a pre-purchase question.

Comment: The laptop I'm planning to buy is the second one on this page(the $1,299 model): http://www.dell.com/us/p/alienware-14/pd.aspx . It has both a backlit keyboard an a web camera.

Comment: The wireless card is apparently based on Atheros -- which should work fine under Ubuntu.